# Android Button Text - Render emoji

Tags: android, button, fonts, emoji

I have set a button text to a string that has emoji in it but they are displayed as question marks (?).

Is this to do with the button font. If so please let me know which font I should assign the button so that the emoji is displayed on the button.

Answer (score 0):

check this:
this project insert Emoji's in text box without font...
the fonts is not supported in old android versions (i.e you will get mono color icons instead of colorful ones)!
[here](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon)